# Codeigniter validate POST and array data

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am trying to validate both an array

```
$this->form_validation->set_data();
```

and POST data

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules();
```

In the same Method...

When trying to use both validation types in my controller it seems that the array validation is removing all the data from the POST fields. I am grabbing order line items using JS and sending them through as JSON and decoding (from a table that is not a part of the form but the values get added to a hidden form field to grab using post still), and the customer details added within a form itself.

The issue I have is each validation I have written (POST and Array) work perfectly fine independently but when trying to run both, on page submit the POST data (being validated with `$this->form_validation->set_rules()`) is being lost...

As the hidden field isn't being validated in the same way, the data is being retained...

Answer (score 0):

Anyone needing to know this after looking it up (spent so long on this before even posting the question)

For each validation group you setup, you must run the validation using `$this->form_validation->run()` before moving onto the next group/method.

To validate POST data create all your rules then immediately run it:

```
    // Order Post Validations
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("firstname", "First Name", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("lastname", "Last Name", "trim|required");
    //run this section
    $this->form_validation->run();
```

Then keep going,

```
    $this->form_validation->set_data($ValidationData);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($ValidationRules);

    //run this section
    $this->form_validation->run();
```

Turns out CI will over-write any existing validations you have done when you set a new group (even when trying to run them together as separate arrays/groups).

Comment: Another options _might_ be to merge the `$_POST` array with `$ValidationData` and use the resulting array as the argument to `set_data()`; Obviously, you need to set all applicable rules before `$this->form_validation->run();`